# Div sizing to fit image

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am still in the process of completing the rest of the page but I am having a very minor problem. The problem is my image div is not the same height as the container. The image is the proper size the image div is just a bit smaller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="image">
        <img src="halie-west-25xggax4bSA-unsplash.jpg" alt="leaves and trees">
    </div>
    <div id="form">
        <fieldset id="info">    
            <h1>Let's do this!</h1>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" required id="first-name">
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="last-name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input required type="email" id="email">
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <label for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="number" required id="phone-number">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" required id="password">
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" required id="confirm-password">
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div id="submit-button">
        <button id="submit" type="submit" method="post">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

#form {
    
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
       
}

#info {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -20px black;
    
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
}

#info h1{
    text-align: left;
}
.column{
    margin:10px;
}

.column label{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding:5px;
    
}
#info input{
    
    align-items: end;
}
#submit{
    height: 3rem;
    width:12rem;
    margin: 3rem 0 0 3rem;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}
#image{
    position: relative;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
   
    
}
#image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    
    
}
#container{
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I just wanted to solve this before I go on because it will not look right while I'm finishing up the login page. I have used chatgpt to try to solve this and I have searched and have had no luck. I do not really have any front end experience so that is why this small thing is puzzling me. I'm sure it is a simple fix.

Comment: `The image is the proper size the image div is just a bit smaller.` does this mean the image will be cropped?

Comment: i want the div that the picture is in to be about 35% and I want to take up the whole div with that picture without any whitespace below it

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want:

- the image to take 35% of the width and rest should be taken by form
- the image should take full height of the viewport
- there should be no whitespace below the image

I tested the following for different viewport dmensions:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#form {
    flex: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}

#info {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -20px black;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 10px;
}

.column label {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

#info input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#submit {
    height: 3rem;
    width: 12rem;
    margin: 3rem 0 0 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#image {
    flex: 0 0 35%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
```